# Initial value of select not set in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS 1.3 app I have a form on which I get model and possible values for select controls asynchronously from backend. When I get model value before values used in `ng-options`, no options becomes selected in select control.
I managed to reproduce this behaviour:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.model = { value: 101 };

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.model.values = [100, 101, 102, 103];
  }, 1000);

});
```

view:

```
Options: <select ng-model="model.value"
      ng-options="v for v in model.values">
      <option value="">Select some...</option>
    </select>
```

After timeout model has its old value 101 but no option is selected.
Currently I find a workaround by using `ng-if="model.values"` on select, but I feel that there should be better way to do it.

Could somebody explain why option is not selected?

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4opZRJzdDfJhSNJx8RMF

EDIT: I opened Plunkr in Firefox and I started to work, then I back to Chrome and it didn't work looks like crossbrowser issue...

Comment: This appears to be specific to angular 1.3;  The code works correctly in angular 1.2, and in the current version 1.4.6

Comment: I'm unsure but I suspect this should be closed as unreproducible since the issue demonstrated only affects specific framework versions, and is not present in the current stable release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @PrimosK about issue.

The solution is to add tracking:

```
 ng-options="v for v in model.values track by v"
```

example in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/45VVAh3H4ZvRky9LSexu?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a [regression](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9714) in AngularJs 1.3.x.

The example you provided works fine in AngularJs 1.2.x and 1.4.x.

Comment: Updating project to AngularJs 1.4 solves this problem (yesterday I made stupid mistake testing on Plunker, I check this again and it works)